# How to Mock test for sending email post signup using celery in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery, django-testing

Post signup of an user in `RegisterUserAPIView`, i'm using a `celery` task to send email for verification.

`views.py`

```
class RegisterUserAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterUserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            # Get the email from serializer and use it to send email for email verification.
            user_email = serializer.validated_data['email']
            send_verification_email_task.delay(user_email = user_email)

            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`task.py`

```
def send_verification_email_task(user_email):
    ...
    response = send_verification_email(user_email=user_email)
    ...
    return "Successfully sent verification email to %s" % user_email
```

`email.py`

```
def send_verification_email(user_email):
    ...
    try:
        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            subject = email_subject,
            body = text_content,
            from_email = email_from,
            to = [email_to]
        )
        email_message.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        email_message.send()

        response = { "status" : 200 }

    except Exception:
        response = { "status" : 400 }

    return response
```

I tried the following test scenarios

1. I called `post` request using the `client` api but that sends an email each time test cases are run.
2. I tried the following mock test scenario but that still shows that my code lines are not covered. This is the test case i tried here.

```
class EmailTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_send_verification_email_task_success(self):
        with patch('auth_service.views.send_verification_email_task.delay') as mock_task:
            user_email = 'testuser@example.com'

            # Mock the send method of the send_verification_email_task
            mock_task.return_value = 'Successfully sent verification email to testuser@example.com'

            # Call the Celery task
            result = send_verification_email_task.delay(user_email=user_email)

            # Assert that the delay method of the send_verification_email task was called with the correct email
            mock_task.assert_called_once_with(user_email=user_email)

            # Assert the expected return value
            self.assertEqual(result, f"Successfully sent verification email to {user_email}")
```

I want to know how can i perform tests for sending email here along with signing up the user ?

Comment: I generally use mailhog (https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/) to test email features. Configure django settings to use mailhog server as mail server while running for test environment. You can easily get the sent mail content and assert whatever you like. I use django send_mail feature (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/) to send email in API views, so no need to configure anything in views. I do not know much about celery.... Hope it helps.